# Which parameter to pass to glGet for getting current framebuffer in OpenGLES iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, render-to-texture

I know to use glGet to get various parameters. I need to know how to get the current GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES and get the GLuint type framebuffer id.

I need to use renderToTexture. This will make one of the classes code easier when switching back to normal framebuffer.

Comment: good Q. the same thing is coming up for me w/ iOS 5's GLKit, the point of which is to hide the existence of framebuffers, but so far i haven't found another way of rendering to textures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter you’re looking for is `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING_OES`.